# Definition of period of a decimal representation of a number

Tags: elementary-number-theory, decimal-expansion

I need to define the period of a decimal representation of a number!!

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Period of a decimal representation of a number may be defined in terms of cyclic numbers:

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_number#Relation_to_repeating_decimals for fun details

Answer (score 1):

It's just how many digits in the repeated part i.e. 1.23123123... has period 3

Comment: Hi @john, thanks!! But formally is possible??

Comment: well I suppose I could define a sequence by $a_1=N$ and $a_{n+1}=10(a_n-Floor[a_n])$ and then the period is the minimum value of $k$ such that $a_{m+k}=a_m$ for some $m$

Answer (score -1):

PERIOD IN DECIMAL NUMBERS-
Period means that in recurring or in
terminating decimal the repeating decimal is known as period 
Example-
     7.9999........ continuously goes
So, 
Here 9 is period because only 9 repeat continuously.

Comment: This is not right; the period is the *number of digits* that repeat, not the repeating sequence of digits.  Also, your example is misleading: $7.999\!\ldots$ is in fact equal to $8$.